# how to use unnamed non-type parameters for a template

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming

I am reading a text book on meta programming. It mentions that typically non-type template parameters should named as UPPERCASE, and this could result in naming conflict with macro names. One way to resolve this is to avoid naming the non-type template (as illustrated below). My question, if the parameter does not have a name, how can it be used in the coding? Would I just use a literal in its place?

example:

```
template <typename A, bool = false>
class test
```

Comment: You can avoid the name in a forward declaration of the template, but generally not in the definition.  Personally, I would not use all uppercase here.

Comment: @VaughnCato got you. It seems easier to avoid using upper case than to avoid naming a variable.